# How do test the title is showing in full length and not displaying with a dotted line with cypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I am new to working with cypress. I want to test the title text with any length is showing completely with full length and not dotted. I tested the title like below but still, I do not know how to check if the title with long length is displaying with dotted or not!! Thank you for any help.

```js
cy.get(selectors.Content)   
  .find(selectors.dataComponent('title'))     
  .should('be.visible')     
  .and('not.be.empty')
```

Comment: Please add the html code and also the screenshot of how its visually seen on the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test that there is no ellipsis, try

```js
cy.get(selectors.Content)    
  .find(selectors.dataComponent('title'))      
  .should('be.visible')      
  .and('not.be.empty')  

cy.get(selectors.Content)    
  .find(selectors.dataComponent('title'))      
  .invoke('text')
  .should('not.contain', '...')
```

Or more strict,

```js
cy.get(selectors.Content)    
  .find(selectors.dataComponent('title'))      
  .invoke('text')
  .should(title => expect(title.endsWith('...')).to.eq(false))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the full length,

```js
cy.get(selectors.Content)    
  .find(selectors.dataComponent('title'))      
  .invoke('text')
  .should('have.length', 20)
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, unfortunately, titles are constantly changing